# Openssl needs to be enabled (ZF2 installation)

Tags: php, openssl, zend-framework2, wamp, composer-php

First of all I realize this may be a possible duplicate, but I've looked at the other thread and that does not resolve my issue.

Basically I'm trying to install Zend Framework 2 and am trying the following command on a WAMP stack setup:

```
php composer.phar install
```

I get an error (You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https) which I have tried the following for:

1. From the WAMP UI, changed the php.ini line 'extension=php_openssl.dll'
2. From the WAMP UI, confirmed that php_openssl has a tick next to it
3. Changed both php.ini files in wamp\bin\php\php.5.4.12 (one is called development and the other production) with the line 'extension=php_openssl.dll'

Still, it produces the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `extension=php_openssl.dll` to `wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini`

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian mentioned, just add the line to php.ini in the specified directory. Or a better approach would be to find this line of code

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and just remove the semi-colon before it. I have this code in line 970 in my wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\php.ini file. It should somewhere around there if you're using the latest version of WAMP. Or just press CTRL+F and search of this bit of code. Hope this helps.